# F5 Big-IP client on Linux

Tags: f5-big-ip

I'm trying to connect VPN using official F5 client on linux..

But whatever I try I always receive same error:

```
2023-05-19,13:05:26:755, 412653,412653,, 48, /CustomQApplication.h, 173, 
void f5::qt::CustomQApplication::quitIfNoSession(), 
Qutting application because no valid session exist
```

Tried multiple debian-based distros.. (latest Ubuntu server, debian from oldstable to sid, ArchLinux with f5vpn AUR package).. still same error..

Anyone experience the same, or knows any solution?